# Checking the Background Color of Excel file using EPPlus library

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using the Open Source `EPPlus` library which allows you to read Spreadsheet files like Excel. Now, I have an Excel file but I want to check the `Background Color` of a Cell before I get the value of a cell. However, I don't know what `enum` to use. Here is my example code below:

```
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
            {
                ExcelWorkbook workbook = package.Workbook;

                ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

                ExcelRange theCell = currentWorksheet.Cells[8, 1];
                if (theCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor == whatShouldBeTheEnumHere)
                {
                  String getValue = theCell.Value.ToString();
                }

            }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer to my own question :-) I found out that `BackgroundColor` has an `RGB` property and that's what I used to get the value of color that I want to test. This is the code

```
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
        {
            ExcelWorkbook workbook = package.Workbook;

            ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

            ExcelRange theCell = currentWorksheet.Cells[8, 1];
            if (theCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb == Color.Yellow.A.ToString("X2") + Color.Yellow.R.ToString("X2") + Color.Yellow.G.ToString("X2") + Color.Yellow.B.ToString("X2"))
            {
              String getValue = theCell.Value.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Or of course I could use a function to return the HexValue like

```
   if (theCell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb == ColorHexValue(Color.Yellow))
      {
        String getValue = theCell.Value.ToString();
      }
```

And the the `function` to return the Hex Value:

```
   private String ColorHexValue(System.Drawing.Color C)
    {
        return C.A.ToString("X2") + C.R.ToString("X2") + C.G.ToString("X2") + C.B.ToString("X2");
    }
```

Comment: The function works, but there is a simpler way to do that.  Just use `Color.Yellow.ToArgb().ToString("X")`.  It is the exact same output.  Make it an extension method if you need even more convenience.